# regular expression - php preg_split result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to split a sentence by some regular expression 
but I can't get the result exactly as I imagined.

```
pattern = /[!.\\n]+[^.\d*]/
str = 'immediate! availability. of PHP 5.3.29.a';
preg_split($pattern,$str);
```

result looks like this

```
    array (
       0 => 'immediate',
       1 => 'availability',
       2 => 'of PHP 5.3.29',
       3 => '',
    )
```

but I want the result to look like this..

```
 array (
     0 => 'immediate!',
     1 => 'availability.',
     2 => 'of PHP 5.3.29.',
     3 => 'a',
 )
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split according to the space which was preceded by `!` or `.` symbols or a word boundary which was followed by a lowercase letter again followed by a  word boundary.

```
<?php
$yourstring = "immediate! availability. of PHP 5.3.29.a";
$regex = '~(?<=[!.]) |\b(?=[a-z]\b)~';
$splits = preg_split($regex, $yourstring);
print_r($splits);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => immediate!
    [1] => availability.
    [2] => of PHP 5.3.29.
    [3] => a
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [**Lookaround**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as well

```
(?<=\.|!) *(?=\D)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/qE6oS6/3)

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    \.                       '.'
   |                        OR
    !                        '!'
  )                        end of look-behind
   *                       ' ' (0 or more times)
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    \D                       non-digits (all but 0-9)
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thanks!! Your explaination